# What is Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, motivation

I asked few questions on Stack Overflow and got the perfect solutions for my questions in no time. Thanks a ton to all you folks.

But I am just wondering, who are the people who are answering my queries and what encourages them to answer these questions?

Is it a knowledge sharing platform? Can anyone please tell me?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meta stackoverflow.

Comment: see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/why-do-programmers-help-each-other-without-pay

Answer (score 12):

In many cases, it's the same people who were asking the questions a decade ago :)

Comment: Nice answer! Very true

Comment: With one glitch: there was no SO back then :(

Answer (score 6):

The same people who've answered questions on other forums for years and years, and mailing lists before that.

Comment: Not all of them :)

Comment: I can't even fathom the ridiculousness of that response.

Comment: @silky I don't know what that means :\

Comment: I potentially took your comment the wrong way; I interpreted it as 'not all the same people', if it meant that, my response was of the form 'that is so obvious it goes without saying, I can't imagine what else you're referring to'. I guess we can assign it to an argumentative morning on meta and leave it be :)

Comment: I assume Rex meant that there are people answering questions, who weren't before Stack Overflow. ( btw, it's late, here in the US. )

Answer (score 2):

We just can't resist. Money isn't everything in life. We want to bond, sometimes don't know how. Helping others help life be more bearable.

Comment: And the little bit of appreciation helps...